# Date picker is not working in codeigniter and no dropdown is showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, datepicker

I'm trying to get the date from this following date picker but it is not working and no drop down is showing!

```
<div class="dateDiv form-group <?=form_error('date') ? 'has-error' : '' ?>" >
     <label for="date">
            <?=$this->lang->line("invoice_date")?> <span class="text-red">*</span>
     </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="<?=set_value('date')?>" >
      <span class="text-red">
            <?php echo form_error('date'); ?>
      </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs datepicker-dates" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y') ?>">
```